# Is Lipschitz norm the other name for Lipschitz constant?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, lipschitz-functions

I am seeing the term Lipschitz norm used in some papers and denoted by $$\|\cdot\|_{Lip}$$

Is it the other name for Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lipschitz constant is only a semi-norm, unless there is some boundary condition or some other additional condition. Constants have Lipschitz constant zero.

In practice this means that the symbol you mention may mean either 
$$
\|u\|_{\mathrm{Lip}} := \sup_x\sup_{h\ne 0} \frac{|u(x+h)-u(x)|}{|h|},$$
or
$$
\|u\|_{\mathrm{Lip}} := \sup_x\sup_{h\ne 0} \frac{|u(x+h)-u(x)|}{|h|} + \|u\|_\infty.
$$
The first is sometimes called "homogeneous" and the second "inhomogeneous" norm, but this is Sobolev space terminology.

Comment: How does the "homogeneous" not a semi-norm as opposed to a norm?
 It seems to remain zero for constant functions.

Comment: Yes, the homogeneous one is a semi norm, unless you pose some boundary conditions or you quotient constants out or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think is related, but not the same. If you have $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$, then you can define the Lipschitz norm as:

$$||f||_{Lip}:=\sup_{x,y\in X,x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}$$

with $d(x,y)$ the metric of $X$. As defined above, $||f||_{Lip}$ could be $+\infty$. The functions for which this isn't true are the Lipschitz functions. And more specifically, the least number $M$ for which $||f||_{Lip}\leq M$ is the Lipschitz constant!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
[f]_{x,D}=\sup_{x,y\in D, x\ne y}\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}},~~~~0<\alpha\leq 1,
\end{align*}
is called unfiromly Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha$ in $D$, see *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, David Gilberg/Neil S. Trudinger.

So it is $\alpha=1$ for Lipschitz case.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: So it is Holder constant of exponent $1$.

Comment: Hmm...A little too cryptic response.  Are you providing a definition of Lipschitz norm and relating it to another mathematical concept namely "holder continuity"? (The question mainly was concerned about the relation between Lip norm and Lip constant.)

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your question, sorry.